# Redirect Tailing Dash in URL from Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to 301 redirect some dash included at the end of some URLs using either mod rewrite or redirect.

There many URL affected by this structure.

```
http://example.com/nested/any-name-.html

to 

http://example.com/nested/any-name.html
```

I found this but it doesn't work with the .html at the end.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-$ http://example.com/nested/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-(\.html)?$ $1$2 [L,R=301]
```